# Getting Error 10293 while inserting a row to a hive table having array as one of the fileds

Tags: hive

I have a hive table created using the following query:

```
create table arraytbl (id string, model string, cost int, colors array <string>,size array <float>)
row format delimited fields terminated by ',' collection items terminated by '#';
```

Now , while trying to insert a row:

```
insert into mobilephones values 
("AA","AAA",5600,colors("red","blue","green"),size(5.6,4.3));
```

I get the following error:

```
FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10293]: Unable to create temp file for insert values Expression of type TOK_FUNCTION not supported in insert/values
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The syantax to enter values in complex datatype if kinda bit weird, however this is my personal opinion.

You need a dummy table to insert values into hive table with complex datatype.

```
insert into arraytbl select "AA","AAA",5600, array("red","blue","green"), array(CAST(5.6 AS FLOAT),CAST(4.3 AS FLOAT)) from (select 'a') x;
```

And this is how it looks after insert.

```
hive> select * from arraytbl;
OK
AA  AAA 5600    ["red","blue","green"]  [5.6,4.3]
```