# How to insert array<map<string,int>> into hive table?

Tags: hive, hiveql, beeline

I have a hive table as follows:

```
0: jdbc:hive2://Desktop:10000> desc tb_test2;
+-------------+-------------------------+----------+
|  col_name   |        data_type        | comment  |
+-------------+-------------------------+----------+
| name        | string                  |          |
| score_list  | array<map<string,int>>  |          |
+-------------+-------------------------+----------+
```

I want to insert data like this:

```
A   [{"math":100,"english":90,"history":85}]  
B   [{"math":95,"english":80,"history":100}]  
C   [{"math":80,"english":90,"histroy":100}]
```

I have tried like this:

```
0: jdbc:hive2://Desktop:10000> insert into tb_test2 values("A",Map("math":100,"english":90,"history":85));
```

but got the error:

```
Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:42 cannot recognize input near '"math"' ':' '100' in constant (state=42000,code=40000)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think comma should be used, and you need to specify array too.

```
insert into tb_test2 select "A", array(map("math",100,"english",90,"history",85)) from (select 1) x;
```

Comment: Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10293]: Unable to create temp file for insert values Expression of type TOK_FUNCTION not supported in insert/values (state=42000,code=10293)

Comment: Thanks for your reply,but this answer give me above Error....

Comment: @needhelp try updated answer? it seems necessary to select from a dummy table, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52330141/getting-error-10293-while-inserting-a-row-to-a-hive-table-having-array-as-one-of)

Comment: thanks for your help....is there a way to put 3 maps into only one map?

Comment: I don't understand "put 3 maps into one map". Could you show an example of the desired output?

Comment: now I got was:[{"math":100},{"english":90},{"history":85}] ,there are 3 maps,is there a way to put them into one map? I learning a complicated `hive UDF experiment`,so I need this structure.Thanks

Comment: like this:[{"math":100,"english":90,"history":85}]

Comment: @needhelp sure, I've edited my answer to achieve that.

Comment: Well done man! that `from (select 1) x;` was the missing piece between me and actual `hive` stored data